# Celery execute tasks in the order they get called (during runtime)

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a task consisting of subtasks in a chain. How can I ensure a second call of this task does not start before the first one has finished?

```
@shared_task
def task(user):
    res = chain(subtask_1.s(), # each subtask takes ~1 hour
            subtask_2.s(),
            subtask_3.s())

    return res.apply_async()
```

A django view might now trigger to call this task:

```
# user A visits page that triggers task
task.delay(userA)
# 10 seconds later, while task() is still executing, user B visits page
task.delay(userB)
```

This leads to the tasks racing each other instead of being executed in sequential order. E.g. once a worker has finished with `subtask_1()` of the first task, it begins working on `subtask_1()` of the second task, instead of `subtask_2()` and `subtask_3()` of the first one.

Is there a way to elegently avoid this? I guess the problem is the order the subtasks get added to the queue.

1. I have already set worker `--concurreny=1`, however that still doesn't change the order he consumes from the queue.
2. [Official docs (task cookbook)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) seem to offer a solution which I don't understand and doesn't work for me unfortunately.
3. Perhaps include a blocking mechanism within the task, after the chain, with a `while not res.ready(): sleep(1)` kind of hack?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for first task to finish and then execute second one like this.

```
res = task.delay(userA)
res.get() # will block until finished
task.delay(userB)
```

But it will block the calling thread until first one finished. You can chain tasks to avoid blocking, but for that you have to modify task signature a little to accept task result as argument.

```
@shared_task
def task(_, user): signature takes one extra argument
    # skipped
```

and

```
from celery.canvas import chain


chain(task.s(None, userA), task.s(userB))()
```

Comment: Yes, ideally I would want the behaviour as described in your chain. However, is there a way to dynamically create, execute and even modify chains like that during run-time? Since I don't know when a second (or third,..) task will be called, is it possible to append tasks to an already executing chain? Thank you for your help!